# Magento 2 call setTemplate return null data

Tags: magento2, cart-items

I am calling below code in my addtocart.phtml to get cart item data

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer")->setTemplate("Magento_Checkout::cart/item/default_custom.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

but it returns null array.Please let me know why this code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use $block instead of $this. For your case:

```
<?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer")->setTemplate("Magento_Checkout::cart/item/default_custom.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

Make sure you pass available data to that block for display

Comment: ,still not working.same result.